# Are there any NLP tools for Esperanto?

Tags: technology

Given that Esperanto is a very regular language, I would imagine that it would be easy to build morphological analysers and even syntactic parsers; parts-of-speech tagging is almost free due to the relevant markers -o/-a/-e/...

I have not come across any tools for natural language processing specifically for Esperanto, though. Is there just no interest in it?

Comment: If there aren't any, this would be a fun project to work on.

Comment: I agree! Years ago I started on a morphological analyser, but then didn't have time to complete it... But it looks so tempting!

Comment: I think Google Translate uses morphological analysis to translate from/to Esperanto.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify by saying what NLP stands for.

Comment: Natural Language Processing -- I assumed that the combination with 'tools' would rule out the other common reading of 'Neurolinguistic Programming'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some literature on using Esperanto (or other constructed or auxiliary languages, including some that are not intended for speaking) as a tool for translating between natural languages. One keyword for finding such works is *interlingua* (a technical term for such an intermediate language used in translations), although obviously this turns up primarily information about the naturalistic auxiliary language of the same name.

PS: The open source software Apertium can translate from Esperanto to English and from English, Spanish, French and Catalan to Esperanto. I tried translation from Esperanto to English, which turned out to be surprisingly good. (My Esperanto isn't good enough yet to judge the other direction.) I think with a bigger dictionary it would easily be better than Google's translator, and that's quite an achievement for a rule based translation system. It looks almost as if it should be feasible to develop software that accurately translates texts written in a controlled subset of Esperanto into every European language.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that Esperanto was a candidate for an interlingua in MT, though I have never actually come across a system that uses it. And its regularity was always given as a prime argument in favour of this application.

Comment: This is probably the article you're looking for about using Esperanto as an intermediate language in machine translation:

[History and Heritage of the DLT (Distributed Language Translation) project](http://www.mt-archive.info/Witkam-2006.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

About 10 years ago I found a software written in ruby which would extract prefixes, suffixes and roots from any esperanto word; I could not find it today. Still I remember the code was surprisingly short given the task, which made me think esperanto was the first "object-oriented" natural language. And makes me think that esperanto NLP software exist today. Here are two NLP articles on esperanto with respect to [lexicography](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2016/pdf/265_Paper.pdf) and [teaching](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W19-6302.pdf) that may prove useful.
I'm an intermediate esperanto speaker and a native French speaker; I find Google Translate and Apertum from French to Esperanto pretty good (better than some Google Translate translations from English to French).
ĝis baldaŭ! Majol'

Answer (score 1):

@aweigold (but not only) It would, really, be fun to work out an NLP model for Esperanto. If there are interested persons out there, even a GitHub project could be started.
Presently, I am playing with an idea to create an Esperanto language model for spaCy (which does not exist, to my best knowledge).  I still am a beginner with spaCy, though.
And what about Toki Pona? :-)

@mayeulk The first link to Eckhard Bick's paper ('lexicography') is not valid any longer. To obtain the paper, you need to go to [enter link description here](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2016/index.html), download the whole of the proceedings, and from the 'pdf' folder select paper_265.pdf. Anyway, thanks a lot for the indication.