# Are there full-scale NLP models for Esperanto?

Tags: information-technology

I am playing with an idea to create an Esperanto language model for spaCy, but before I even start, I would like to learn if something similar possibly exists already, eventually for a different NLP framework. TIA.

PS. I am aware of Oliver Mason's posting [Are there any NLP tools for Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/13/1576) of Aug 23, 2016, but my matter is different.